# Parsing JSON using json.net, Array serialized as properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize json data formated in a way I haven't seen before.
I'm using json.net and C#.

The class corresponding to the json should be like this:

```
class Example
{
   public Person[] data { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how the json looks like:

```
{
   data: {
      "123": ["SWE", "Steve"],
      "221": ["USA", "Bob"],
      "245": ["CAN", "Susan"]
   }
}
```

Is it possible using attributes or do I have to do it all myself?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Always [verify you have valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) first.

Comment: So to clarify, I do not control the json data, It is as it is. And my question is, is it parsable?

Comment: To clarify, that's not JSON then. You should contact whoever provides that data and tell them they're not generating valid JSON.

Comment: There is a way if you use Newtonsoft nuget library. By using this, you can cast your json to dictionary object and then Person object

Comment: Thanks for the answer mason. Then I can stop trying to parse it.

Comment: @Rios Are you sure you are not missing quotes around data like `"data" :`

Comment: Thanks Lali! That seems to be working. 
I found this answer that answered the same question I had.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score -5):

Your variables on the *data* object (123, 221, 245) would a type `List<string>()`.

With JSON.NET, your schema needs to match your data; types and names.

EDIT: Looking at your Person object, your POCO classes don't seem correct. You would need a structure like this:

```
public Data data { get; set; }
```

where data is...

```
public class Data
{
    public List<string> 123 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, that's not valid. It's not a list of strings. But anways the JSON isn't valid JSON so this is irrelevant.

Comment: And in any case `123` is not a valid name in C#